# Escape apostrophe before submit POST

Tags: php

I have a group of `checkboxes` which are loaded from a `database`. These are all songs, so some of them have an apostrophe in it. When clicking `submit` with `method=post` then everything gets posted on next page, however the songs with an apostrophe are not complete. It breaks right before the apostrophe.

Ex: `Can't Breathe` becomes `Can`

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(isset($_POST['chk_album'])){
  foreach($_POST['chk_album'] as $key=>$val){
   echo $val; 
  }
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_album[]" data-album="echo" value="Can't Breathe">
```

**SQL:**

```
$dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM $album";
$dbResult = mysqli_query($dbCon, $dbQuery) or die("Error");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
    $id = $row["Id"];
    $title = addslashes($row["Title"]);
    $album = $row["Album"];
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chk_album[]' value='" . $title . "' />";

    }
```

I did try looking for answers on Google, but couldn't find anything specific to my problem. I think.

Comment: Hm.. can't recreate the issue. Btw, you are missing closing bracket in code (guess that it is just copy-paste error).

Comment: This code **ought to work**. You may have issue with *double* quotes and need to use AddSlashes, but not with single quotes. What do you use to POST that form? Check that code.

Comment: Actually, your rendered HTML output is probably different -> only way to recreate your issue is to use this HTML: <input type="checkbox" name="chk_album[]" data-album="echo" value='Can't Breathe'>
Wrap value in double quotes, to get correct HTML output.

Comment: I'd bet something that @nevermind has the right of it. This, however, will only shift the problem somewhere else...

Comment: Yes, you're right @nevermind! If you can post this as answer I can mark it as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When taking a string of *text* and inserting it into an HTML document, use `htmlspecialchars()` to make it safe and convert characters that have special meaning.

PHP assumes that you will delimit attribute values with `"` so it won't convert `'` by default. You can deal with this by passing an extra flag.

```
$html = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Thus:

```
$html_title = htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chk_album[]' value='" . $html_title . "' />";
```

(and remove `$title = addslashes($row["Title"]);` since `addslashes` is never a good solution for anything and just puts weird characters in your data here).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_album[]" data-album="echo" value="Can\'t Breathe">
```

Comment: The thing is, the value is filled in from database so I can't change it manually.

Comment: Use the PHP function `mysql_escape_string` which will escape the characters for you. So something like `echo mysql_escape_string($value);`

Comment: That would be good when requesting data, but it's not going to help when reading them. You want `addslashes()`. Also, **never** use `mysql_escape_string`. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` (better yet: switch to PDO).

Comment: Both functions: the result I get now is `Can\` I'll update OP with SQL code